# Free software for calculating the net charge of an amino acid as a function of pH?

Tags: biochemistry, software, amino-acids

Does a free software for calculating the net charge of amino acids as a function of pH exist?

Answer (score 4):

I like [MarvinSketch](https://www.chemaxon.com/marvin/sketch/index.php). You can run it in your browser or on your computer. Under Insert > Template, you can find all the amino acids. Once you've inserted one, select Calculations > Protonation > Isoelectric point and click OK. You'll get a window that looks like this showing the net charge versus pH (I picked a pretty boring one, but other amino acids produce more complex curves):

[image: Isoelectric point graph]

Comment: Needs Java. Thats a bummer. :(

Answer (score 2):

I came accidentally across this old not fully answered question. Recently I wrote a web application mainly for the calculation of physico-chemical property of proteins ([Prot pi](https://www.protpi.ch/Calculator/ProteinTool)). But you can also use this tool to calculate/estimate the titration curve of single amino acids. You can enter the single letter code for your amino acid (e.g. k for Lysine):
[image: The input for the calculation]

And there you get the net charge in function of the pH:
[image: Output: The titration curve]